# “x + b < constraint” for “domain_start < x < domain_end”. Solution for “b” only according to the set “x” domain

Tags: inequalities

I am giving a really simple example that describes my problem really clear.

> Example: "x + b < 50" for  "3 < x < 6"

i need a solution set for my coefficient (e.g. for "b") that satisfies all possible values of the defined domain of a variable (e.g. "3 < x < 6") for the given function (e.g. "x + b < 50").

I need one simple output "b<=44" but i still have not been able to get a result without the defined domain variable intruding in the solution (e.g. (b <= 44&& 3 < x < 6)||(44 < b < 47 && 3 < x < 50-b))

The code below that should normally work produces no results:

> FullSimplify[Reduce[  { x + b < 50 ,  x > 3 , x< 6 }, {b}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True], x > 3 &&  x<6]

Comment: `CylindricalDecomposition[x + b < 50 && 3 < x < 6, {b, x}]` *almost* gets there.

Comment: Reduce[x + b < 50 && 3 < x < 6, {b,x}]  does the same =/ unfortunately  like everything i have tried so far they include x in their solutions

Comment: When cross-posting, please link the threads together: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1177429

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ForAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html) for this kind of problem:

```
Reduce[ForAll[x, 3 < x < 6, x + b < 50], b]
(* b <= 44 *)
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed! You can't imagine how much time i spent on it, its really not that intuitive! Thanks a lot